# QGIS 2.18 crashes every time I zoom to a layer

Tags: qgis

When I zoom to any layer, QGIS 2.18 crashes without an error code. I also tried completely changing the CRS, removing all map services. What else can I try?

The CRS was WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. I also tried changing it all to NAD83HARN Mercator and the same problem persists. The "zoom to layer" seems to be the only trigger to this crash. The zoom starts to happen, then the moving blue "thinking" indicator at the bottom of the screen moves, then it stops, and then it crashes. The only layers are shapefiles.

Comment: What QGIS version are you using?

Comment: Using QGIS 2.18. All of the layers were set in WGS84. All of my layers are shapefiles. Everytime I click on "zoom to layer", QGIS starts the zoom and then locks up, then closes. What other details should I be providing?

Comment: I then converted all the layers and data frame to a HARN PCS, same thing happens. I also removed the map services. Could this possibly be a bug with one of the installed plugins?

Comment: Edit your question with all the information in your comments. There is an edit button under your question. Once done the community will vote to reopen your question if everything is clear.

Comment: Does this happen in every QGIS project? Have you tried it in a new project with a single layer?